# Error: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-sns'

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am getting this error when calling my lambda.

"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-sns'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/handler.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
"trace": [
"Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-sns'",

```js
import * as AWS from '@aws-sdk/client-sns';
import { JamaSnsMessage } from './models/jama';
import { region, snsTopicArn } from './utils/constants';
import { log } from './utils/logger';

const client = new AWS.SNS({ region });

/**
 * Publishes given SNS formatted Jama items to SNS topic
 *
 * @param {JamaSnsMessage[]} items
 */
export const publishItems = async (items: JamaSnsMessage[]): Promise<void> => {
  if (!items || items.length <= 0) {
    return;
  }

  for (const item of items) {
    const params = {
      /* eslint-disable */
      MessageStructure: 'json',
      Message: JSON.stringify(item),
      TopicArn: snsTopicArn,
      /* eslint-enable */
    };
    log.info(`Sending jama item: ${JSON.stringify(item)} to sns`);
    await send(params);
  }
};

export const send = async (params: AWS.PublishInput): Promise<void> => {
  try {
    const data = await client.send(new AWS.PublishCommand(params));
    log.info(`Item: ${JSON.stringify(params)} was published with id: ${data.MessageId}`);
  } catch (error) {
    log.error(`Error while publishing message ${JSON.stringify(params)}. Cause: ${error}`);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using V2 of the SDK, use:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create promise and SNS service object
const SNS = new AWS.SNS({apiVersion: '2010-03-31'})
```

And if for size reasons you want to use only the SNS module in your Lambda function, I recommend you use V3 of the AWS SKD for JavaScript. Lambda is still  compatible by default only with V2 of the SDK, but there's a workaround. Here's an [example of creating a function using only modules of the AWS SDK for JavaScrpt - version 3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/lambda-create-table-example.html).

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer as I'm having a similar issue as the OP. Your answer, however is a bit difficult to understand for me. Firstly your comment "The problem is import...", but I'm not sure why that's a problem... unless it's related to your comment later about V2/V3? Secondly, on SO it's good form to provide the answer in your question instead of linking to where the OP can find the answer, as you seem to have done with the linked example. I will go and follow up on the link but it would be good to copy the relevant bit in relation to this question. Thanks heaps!

Comment: I got it resolved and this was an issue with the node version I was using. I updated my node version to 12.X and now it's able to find the library. So, I can say that V3 requires node version 12.X at least. I did not change anything else than the node version.

Comment: Only the V2 AWS SDK is loaded by default in the lambda environment at present. To use V3, you need to include the packages in a layer or with your function yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Install sdk v3

```
npm i @aws-sdk/client-sns
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Node 14 Lambda function when trying to import the DynamoDB V3 client as documented in [AWS SDK for JavaScript v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html).

The function logged:

> Error: Cannot find module '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb" DynamoDB

I followed [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-aws-sdk-latest-version/) to create a Lambda layer and attach it to the Lambda function.

However, I think the process can be simplified - instead of launching an EC2 instance, you can do this over CloudShell. The region that hosts your Lambda does not need to support CloudShell. Simply launch a CloudShell from any region that supports it, then do:

```sh
# Create the directory
$ mkdir -p aws-sdk-layer/nodejs
$ cd aws-sdk-layer/nodejs

# Add the clients you want to use from the new SDK
$ yarn add @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb @aws-sdk/client-apigatewaymanagementapi

# Create the zip file
$ zip -r ../package.zip ../

# Publish the layer
# In the below, change:
#   The layer name (currently node_sdk)
#   The description (currently "My layer")
#   The region
#
# Copy from the response the value of the "LayerVersionArn" key
#
$ aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name node_sdk --description "My layer" --license-info "MIT" --compatible-runtimes nodejs14.x --zip-file fileb://../package.zip --region <specify a region>

# Add the layer to your function
# In the below, change:
#   The function name (currently my-function)
#   Set the layer's ARN to the value of the "LayerVersionArn" key in the response from the previous statement (currently arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:layer:node_sdk:1)
#   The region
#
$ aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name my-function --layers arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:layer:node_sdk:1 --region <specify a region>
```

And you should be good to go!

Answer (score -1):

The issue was with Node version 10.X with V3 sdk. when I updated the node version to 12.X then it started working. I am using AWS CDK so I also needed to update the CDK dependencies to 1.88.0 to get this 12.X support.

Change runtime for lambda in CDK project -

**runtime:** lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_12_X

Comment: odd, I'm using Node.js 12.x but still getting the error. Something to do with my javascript I think...

Answer (score -1):

I ran into a similar problem using AWS Layers and ES modules. Using the absolute specifier for the import fixed the issue for me.

```
import {S3Client, GetObjectCommand} from "file:///opt/nodejs/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js";
```

Comment: This makes it impossible (or cumbersome, at least) to run the code anywhere else than within a Lambda environment, including during tests, local scripts etc. Modules should be sourced by their name, not by their filesystem dependent path. This is not the correct solution.